# Connection refused from localhost service with external config from remote Spring Cloud Config behind proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot Service that retrieves externalized configuration from Spring Cloud Config (which retrieves from a GitHub repo).

When I'm behind a corporate proxy, my local cannot get to the remote Spring Cloud Config service when I run with...

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Java 8
- Maven
- Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE
- Specified `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables with the correct settings
- Using a local `project-settings.xml` file that contains the `<proxies><proxy>...` settings for both `http` and `https` (both are active and correct)
- Passing both `http` and `https` proxy settings on the command line as well via `-D` properties (e.g. `-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=some.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`)

`mvnw -s project-settings.xml -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=some.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxySet=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=some.proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Drun.profiles=myprofile sp
ring-boot:run`

In my real settings, the proxy settings are all correct (and the same for http and https, which is okay) and the spring profile is correct.

I end up getting: `Connection refused: connect`

```
2017-12-01 12:12:10.560  INFO 20652 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: https://my-config-service.my-host.net/
2017-12-01 12:12:12.467  WARN 20652 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "https://my-config-service.my-host.net/my-local-service-name/myprofile": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Is the firewall doing deep packet inspection?  That might cause a problem.

Comment: Any way to check as just a user of the firewall? I have no permissions to view or manage firewall settings. I also have limited knowledge of how to trace this kind of traffic.